# Select last record for each foreign key that match primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am stuck in MySQL query. I have two tables one name is STUDENT and field names is (ID, FullName) where ID is PRIMARY KEY and another table is Student_FEE field is (ID, Student_ID, Date) here Student_ID is foreign key.
When i execute this query i get all the record of but i just want to select only that last row of each Student_ID not all here is image and query.
Remember I Just Need ID 5 and ID 9

```
SELECT Student_FEE.*
FROM Student_FEE
LEFT JOIN Student
ON Student_FEE.ID=Student.ID
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Thanks you so much i have found this , thanks stackoverflow. Here is answer

```
 SELECT Student_FEE.* FROM Student_FEE LEFT JOIN Student
 ON Student_FEE.student_ID = Student.ID 
WHERE Student_FEE.ID IN (SELECT MAX(ID) 
FROM Student_FEE GROUP BY Student_ID)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a group by  adn an in clause

```
  SELECT Student_FEE.*
  FROM Student_FEE 
  LEFT JOIN Student 
  ON Student_FEE.student_ID=Student.ID
  where Student_FEE in ( select max(ID)  
                         from Student_FEE 
                         group by student_ID)
```

Comment: Thanks your last query is correct but only when i run separately. Here is result when i run the your last query

Comment: Thanks your last query is correct but only when i run separately. Here is result when i run the your last query
SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Student_FEE GROUP BY Student_ID

Comment: please read the answer of my question hope you will understand better because here i am not able to post any pic. anyway thatks for your answer.
this query give me error
 #1054 - Unknown column 'moon_creations.Student_FEE' in 'IN/ALL/ANY subquery'

Comment: @AliRazaMarchal   based on your comment i have update the answer .. hope this is what you are looking for